# How do I create my GOTO system?

Tags: python, file, operating-system

Ok, so, I am making an operating system and have started on the file system. I can so far retrieve the current directory, list all the folders within the directory, but now I need to be able to navigate.

In my Operating System, you start it up and it is like a console. The folders are classes. Let me show you some code:

```
class folder:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name
        self.parent = None
    def setparent(self,name):
        if isinstance(name,folder):
            self.parent = n
            self.parent.children.append(self)
root = folder("root")
docs = folder("docs")
test = folder("test")
docs.setparent(root)
test.setparent(docs)
directory = root
def ls():
    for x in directory.children:
        print(x.name)
ls()
```

so at the moment, this script would output 'docs', as docs is the only folder that is a child to root. But I want to be able to get the folder to go to through user input, so say if they could type in 'GOTO docs', ***how would I get the directory set to docs?***

so, lets say that the input is a variable called i, and the user typed in GOTO docs, I know how to get the 'docs' seperate to GOTO, which I have done by using i[5:]. What I now want is to set the directory variable to an instance rather than a string. How would I do this?

Comment: You could loop through `children` of the current directory, looking for one with an equal `name`.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, icktoofay (I apologize if I read your name wrong), I will try that now!

Comment: Just tried it and it works great, also was able to go to previous directory, thank you very much for your time!